# Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1"

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I got two different scripts and combined them to check a specific folder for new file and email that file as attachment.

Here's the code combined:

```
Param (
    $Path = "C:\path"
    )

$File = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-10) }
If ($File)
{   
$emailSmtpServer = "smtp.xxxx.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "587"
$emailSmtpUser = "xxxx@xxxxxx.com"
$emailSmtpPass = "xxxxxxxx"

$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMessage.From = "Xxxx Xxxx <xxxx@xxxxxx.com>"
$emailMessage.To.Add( "xxxx@xxxxxx.com" )
$emailMessage.Subject = "File Test Report"
$emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $false
$emailMessage.Body = "Weekly Report"

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer , $emailSmtpServerPort )
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass );
$attachment = $File
$emailMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)

$SMTPClient.Send($emailMessage) 
}
```

The code works fine, it looks for new file and sends the email except it won't attach the file and I get the following error

```
Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".
At D:\SendEmail2.ps1:24 char:1
+ $emailMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

I think it has something to do with calling the file with `$attachment = $File`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to create a `Attachment` object first and also have to deal with multiple files so replace the following lines:

```
$attachment = $File
$emailMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
```

with:

```
$File | ForEach-Object {
    $filePath = $_.FullName
    $attachment = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($filePath)
    $emailMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
}
```

Comment: `new-object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find
file 'C:\Users\xxxx\File.txt'."
At D:\SendEmail2.ps1:23 char:15`

Why did it copy the new file to C:\Users\xxxx\ ?

Comment: It doesn't copied the files. I changed my script, please give it a another shot.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue as you and this fixed it.
https://community.spiceworks.com/posts/8438625

just change:
$path = "D:\FTP-COR\$($today.Year)\$($today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))"
and add your credentials.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and 
provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I am using PowerShell: (I use .NET so don't forget C#, please don't ask):-)
create a .csv file:

```
$collection | Export-Csv -Path $SaveAs -NoTypeInformation
```

To create the attachment object:

```
[System.Net.Mail.Attachment] $Attachment = [System.Net.Mail.Attachment]::new($SaveAs)
```

Then to attach to the message object:

```
$message.Attachments.Add($Attachment)
```

This should work. I have been using this and it's been working fine. I know it's in PowerShell, but at the core, same .NET